# How to select specific fields of JSON data and output that to another JSON object in NodeJS using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, arrays, node.js, json, select

So i have the following

`foo.bar.output` which gives me something like `array[14]` so it means it contains 14 elements

Now i want to select specific properties within each array index say `array[i]` and store it in a new JSON object

**Sample values**

```
{
  "description" : "sample",
  "link" : "mylink",
  "id" :"myid",
  "deviceName:"mydevice"
},
```

There are 14 such iterations,

In each iteration i want to select only `id` and `deviceName` and store that in a seperate JSON object

So my final JSON object which i created should look like

```
{
  "id":"myid",
  "deviceName:"mydevice"
},
```

I have no experience with jQuery and i am really confused how to solve this issue any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: if i understand you right you can loop exist object and create new one where will you push id and devicename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .map to loop through `foo.bar.output` data and can get an array with filtered properties of an object.

```
var data = [{
  "description" : "sample",
  "link" : "mylink",
  "id" :"1",
  "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
  "description" : "sample",
  "link" : "mylink",
  "id" :"2",
  "deviceName":"mydevice2"
},
{
  "description" : "sample",
  "link" : "mylink",
  "id" :"3",
  "deviceName":"mydevice3"
}]


data.map(({id, deviceName}) => ({id, deviceName})

output:

[ { id: '1', deviceName: 'mydevice1' },
  { id: '2', deviceName: 'mydevice2' },
  { id: '3', deviceName: 'mydevice3' } ]
```

Comment: posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410832/how-to-update-value-in-json-in-nodejs-and-filter-to-exclude-values

Answer (score 2):

You could use map to create a new array of elements with only id and deviceName

```
array.map((element)=>({id:element.id, deviceName: element.deviceName}))
```