# How to update value in JSON in NodeJS and filter to exclude values?

Tags: jquery, arrays, node.js, json, select

```
var data = [{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"1",
   "deviceName":"mydevice1"
},
{
   "description" : "sample",
   "link" : "mylink",
   "id" :"",
   "deviceName":""
}]
```

How do i update `deviceName` where it is empty that is `"deviceName"=""` to `novaluespecified` in my JSON object ??

**Note**

originally it is a huge array so i can't do it for 1 single index

Also i need to filter out all devices named `device1` and NOT include that in my final JSON i searched around and i found `.filter` for including but could not find a function for excluding something

**EDIT**

I would prefer not to use jquery and if possible do it with NodeJS fully.. any help is appreciated :)

and i don't mind using jquery if its absolutely required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below Hope it helps.First I have used [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the value where deviceName is empty `string`.Next I have used [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [indexOF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to filter out the values.

```js
var data = [{
    "description": "sample",
    "link": "mylink",
    "id": "1",
    "deviceName": "mydevice1"
  },
  {
    "description": "sample",
    "link": "mylink",
    "id": "1",
    "deviceName": "mydevice1"
  },
  {
    "description": "sample",
    "link": "mylink",
    "id": "",
    "deviceName": ""
  }
]

let _res = data.map(ele => {
  if (ele.deviceName == "") {

    ele.deviceName = "novaluespecified"
  }
  return ele;

})


console.log(_res)

// filtering out device1


var data2 = [{
    "description": "sample",
    "link": "mylink",
    "id": "1",
    "deviceName": "mydevice1"
  },
  {
    "description": "sample",
    "link": "mylink",
    "id": "1",
    "deviceName": "mydevice1"
  },
  {
    "description": "sample",
    "link": "mylink",
    "id": "",
    "deviceName": ""
  }
]

let _res1 = data2.filter(ele => {

  if (ele.deviceName.indexOf('device1') == -1) {
    return ele;
  }



})
console.log(_res1)
```

Comment: If i wanted to filter 2 devices say device1 and device2 how would i modify this code ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try it like this:

```
var updatedData = data.map(item => item.deviceName == '' ? { ...item, deviceName: 'novaluespecified'} : {...item} )
```

output:

```
[ { description: 'sample',
    link: 'mylink',
    id: '1',
    deviceName: 'mydevice1' },
  { description: 'sample',
    link: 'mylink',
    id: '1',
    deviceName: 'mydevice1' },
  { description: 'sample',
    link: 'mylink',
    id: '',
    deviceName: 'novaluespecified' } ]
```

To filter you can do something like this:

```
data.filter(item => item.deviceName !== 'device1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` for generating the desired output in only one loop.

```js
let data = [{"description" : "sample","link" : "mylink","id" :"1","deviceName":"mydevice1"},{"description" : "sample","link" : "mylink","id" :"1","deviceName":"mydevice1"},{"description" : "sample","link" : "mylink","id" :"","deviceName":""}],
    result = data.reduce((a, {deviceName, ...rest}) => {
      if(deviceName !== "mydevice1") a.push(Object.assign({}, rest, {deviceName: deviceName.trim() === "" ? "novaluespecified" : deviceName}));
      return a;
    } , []);

console.log(result);
```